# How would I import the JES libraries into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jython, pydev

I am new to Java and Jython programming, but I am taking a course. I am used to importing libraries through C++, but I have no idea how to do it with this with Jython. My school wants us to use JES, but that application is rough to use for an experienced programmer. Currently, I am trying to use PyDev for eclipse. How do I import the libraries from JES so I have the JES functions in eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

Import the class.jar from the JES installation to the project by right-clicking on the project > properties > external libraries > add jar/zip/egg, then simply use the statement import to import your whichever file has the function. To call the function, use fileName.function()

Comment: Hello! Great that you took the time to put up this information even if your problem was already solved. Since you are new to this site I'd like to point out that you should accept your own answer it it solves your problem.